# Oracle dmp imported by Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, import, oracle-sqldeveloper, dmp

I'm just new with Oracle DB, I have used Oracle Sql Developer to import dmp file (oracle 11.2.0.2.0, Oracle Sql Developer 19.2.1.247)

[image]

[image]

Everything work ok, but i got **IMP_SD_41-10_20_50** table inserted

[image]

[image]

Can anyone give me a sugggestion!

Comment: i'm not sure how your import job log is also being imported as a table...what does the actual import job log show - is the IMP_SD table listed?

Comment: Thank you, i select the IMP_SD table and it show the log. It says TABLESPACE have not created and other error. I have fixed it.